# How to limit Django-nonrel query result set within Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I have a simple model:

```
class News(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("title"))
    content = models.TextField(default='', verbose_name=_("content"))
    panel = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', verbose_name=_("panel"))
    created = TzDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("date created"))
    lastmodified = TzDateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("date modified"))
```

I want to get the 5 recent news records, and I know that with Google App Engine DB queryset I can get 5 recent records in the following easy way:

```
results = News.all().filter(panel = panel).order('created').fetch(5)
```

With Django running in Google App Engine I would need to do:

```
results = News.objects.filter(panel = panel).order_by('created')[:5]
```

But it will throw exception if there are no news records. I could wrap it within catch exception, but what is the proper and optimized way to limit query results within Django?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
results = News.objects.filter(panel = panel).order_by('created')
if results is not None:
   new_results = results[:5]
```

Comment: Will this be efficient? It looks like it will get all results and then slice first 5?

Comment: Well, there is no such method to limit in 1.2 Django, maybe I am wrong? In docs it says in order to limit I should use slicing:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets